# Android 3.3 and ConstraintLayout problems

Tags: android-studio, android-layout

They are all related to ConstraintLayout.

1. When I hide a Group (Invisible or Gone) the editor (Design and Blueprint) continues to show it.
2. The barriers are always displayed in the margin of the screen (up, down, left or right) and not over, under ... of the view to which it is associated.
3. The behavior of the views in the ConstraintLayout seems to have changed. For example, if an View X has the Constraint UP to another View Y and this View Y becomes visible = Gone, the View X is aligned with the next one that has above. Before this, barriers were needed.

In addition, when updating AS the ConstraintLayout that I had built has been completely deconfigured, I have had to redesign it in another way, I do not know if this will affect the real devices. It's all pretty confusing, I'm about to abandon the project where I work :(

If I redesign the screens under AS 3.3 should they look good on the real devices as I did when designing them in the previous version?

Comment: did you find something about this issue?

Comment: Finally I redesigned the layout until it was seen correctly in this Android update.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was solved in the newest build.

```
Android Studio 3.3.2
Build #AI-182.5107.16.33.5314842, built on February 15, 2019
```

[Get android studio](https://developer.android.com/studio)

Answer (score 0):

I can't help you but I have the same problem! Barriers are really not working properly because they are displayed always in the margins and I can't use them! 
I'm running AS 3.3.0 and yesterday I've updated to AS 3.3.1 but barriers don't work yet

Comment: Maybe it would be convenient to put an incidence on Google

Comment: The bug has been fixed in 3.4 betas. I'm currently running 3.4 beta 5 and finally barriers are working as expected